# Creating RadWindow Completely From C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, radwindow

I am trying to create a RadWindow in my code behind on an Asp.Net site project. I am missing something vital and the RadWindow will not display. Can someone out there provide some positive insight, please?

```
RadWindowManager A = new RadWindowManager();  
RadWindow B = new RadWindow();  
B.Modal = true;  
B.NavigateUrl = "SomePage.Aspx";  
B.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;  
B.ID = "winDow";  
A.Windows.Add(B);  
Controls.Add(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
RadWindow B;
```

to the Control tree in the correct place, which in this case is the Form. If your Form is called form1:

```
RadWindow B = new RadWindow();  
B.Modal = true;  
B.NavigateUrl = "SomePage.Aspx";  
B.VisibleOnPageLoad = true;  
B.ID = "winDow";
this.form1.Controls.Add(B);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Well, it is not allowing me to do "this.myForm"... It is on the page's .cs, and within a public void.. @mjw

Comment: Where does the above code snippet live? Page_Load? Other event handler?

Comment: I created a method below Page_Load, and called it through Page_Load, still no joy... I added "this.Control",  also, and this did not have any noticeable effect...